# How to get Current Store DateTime in Javascript magento2

Tags: magento2, javascript, timezone

How to get **Current Store DateTime** in Javascript magento2. Is any library function available?

Answer (score 0):

**You can use in you js file in Magento 2**

```
var timestamp = new Date().getTime();
var hours = Math.floor((timestamp % (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24)) / (1000 * 60 * 60));
var minutes = Math.floor((timestamp % (1000 * 60 * 60)) / (1000 * 60));
var seconds = Math.floor((timestamp % (1000 * 60)) / 1000);

console.log('Time');
console.log(hours + ":" + minutes + ":" + seconds);
```